# Makefile lazy expansion of rule prerequisite

Tags: makefile

I have a couple of rules which are parametrised as follows:

```
.SECONDEXPANSION:
NAME=default
foo: x-$$(NAME)

bar: NAME=bar
bar: foo

baz: NAME=baz
baz: foo

x-%:
  @echo building $@
```

I would expect the following output when running `make bar`:

```
$ make bar
building x-bar
```

But I see:

```
$ make bar
building x-default
```

Is there a way to delay expansion in a rules' prerequisites until after it is being invoked so I can parametrize the rules like this? I would like to avoid using `define ... endef` etc. because my rules are quite complicated and having another level of `$$` in there would really hurt readability.

Comment: Does it have to be exactly that way? How about `bar: foo-bar` and `foo-%: x-%`?

Comment: Are you sure that readability is advanced by using .SECONDEXPANSION? Its already hard to envision what a makefile looks like at the time of execution but having to take the ramifications of another indirection into account is pure suffering IMHO.

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug in make. Fixed in make 4.4. It yields the output you expected:

```
# make bar
building x-bar
```